# How to draw a signature and save it to disc as a Bitmap?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to do a signature capture program and save the customer signature to a `PNG` or `BMP` format. I have the Picturebox code working great and the results look better than using draw. I can't get the image to save.

```
Imports System.Drawing
Public Class Form1
    Dim color As System.Drawing.Pen = Pens.Black
    Dim bmp As Bitmap

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bmp = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        Static last As New Point
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.DrawLine(color, last.X, last.Y, e.X, e.Y)
        End If
        last = e.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdClear.Click
        bmp = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
        PictureBox1.Image = bmp
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            bmp = PictureBox1.Image
            bmp.Save("c:\temp\test1.bmp")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I would like to see the image of the signature.

Comment: You can embed a **InkCanvas** control, which handles all the drawing automatically (with **ElementHost**)

Answer (score 9):

Never use **`[Control].CreateGraphics`**, unless you need this object for immediate use in a specific environment. To measure the size of text when drawn in a specific graphics context, for example.
When you need the drawing to persist, as painting on the surface of a control, use the Graphics object provided by the [PaintEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs) of the [Paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) event (or similar event, as the [DrawItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem) event of the ComboBox, ListBox, ListView controls).
You'll find this kind of recommendations all over SO (and the Web, in general).

How to proceed:

1. We need an object that can store the Mouse/Pen movements that define a hand-made curve.
2. The object needs to store a new curve definition each time the left button of the mouse is released (or the Pen touch is lost and re-acquired).
3. We need a Graphics object that can convert the cardinal spline curves, defined by the points created by Mouse/Pen movements, to [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) (combinations of curves - outlines that represents a series of smooth vector lines - are often referred to as *Paths* in vector graphics).

Here, the object that stores the movements is a **`Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Point))`**, where the **`Key`** represents a curve and the **`Value`** represents the collection of Points that define that curve.
Each time the Left Button of the Mouse is pressed, a new `Key` is created and a new `List(Of Point)` is associated with the `Key`.
When the Mouse/Pen is moved, the new Point location is added to the current curve's `List(Of Point)`.

The [GraphicsPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath) class can convert the `List(Of Point)` collection to Control Points of a Bezier curve, using the [GraphicsPath.AddCurve()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addcurve) method.
This method accepts an array of Points and a **`Tension`** value as arguments. The `Tension` is a value between `0` and `1` that defines the amount of bending applied to a curve when connecting Points. A value of `0.5f` is used here.

► When we need to paint the drawing on a Bitmap to save the results to disc, we apply the same logic to the Graphics object derived, in this case, from a Bitmap object.
Thus, just one method is used to draw both on the surface of a Control and onto a Bitmap object.
The **`DrawSignature(g As Graphics)`** method in this code.

This is how it works:

[image: Signature Drawing]

**Code that reproduces the procedure described**:

**`pBoxSignature`** is the PictureBox where the signature is drawn
**`pBoxSavedSignature`** is the (smaller) PictureBox used to show the last image saved
**`btnClearSignature`** is the Button used to clear the signature
**`btnSaveSignature`** is the Button used to save the signature to a new Image
**`txtSignatureFileName`** is the TextBox used to enter the signature's file name

```
Private signatureObject As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Point))
Private signaturePen As New Pen(Color.Black, 4)
Private currentCurvePoints As List(Of Point)
Private currentCurve As Integer = -1

Private Sub pBoxSignature_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.MouseDown
    currentCurvePoints = New List(Of Point)
    currentCurve += 1
    signatureObject.Add(currentCurve, currentCurvePoints)
End Sub

Private Sub pBoxSignature_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.MouseMove
    If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left OrElse currentCurve < 0 Then Return
    signatureObject(currentCurve).Add(e.Location)
    pBoxSignature.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub btnClearSignature_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearSignature.Click
    currentCurve = -1
    signatureObject.Clear()
    pBoxSignature.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub btnSaveSignature_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSaveSignature.Click
    Dim signatureFileName = txtSignatureFileName.Text.Trim()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureFileName) Then Return
    If currentCurve < 0 OrElse signatureObject(currentCurve).Count = 0 Then Return

    imgSignature As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) 
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgSignature)
        DrawSignature(g)

        Dim signaturePath As String = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, $"{signatureFileName}.png")
        imgSignature.Save(signaturePath, ImageFormat.Png)
        pBoxSavedSignature.Image?.Dispose()
        pBoxSavedSignature.Image = imgSignature
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub pBoxSignature_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.Paint
    If currentCurve < 0 OrElse signatureObject(currentCurve).Count = 0 Then Return
    DrawSignature(e.Graphics)
End Sub

Private Sub DrawSignature(g As Graphics)
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

    For Each curve In signatureObject
        If curve.Value.Count < 2 Then Continue For
        Using gPath As New GraphicsPath()
            gPath.AddCurve(curve.Value.ToArray(), 0.5F)
            g.DrawPath(signaturePen, gPath)
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**C# Version**

```
private Dictionary<int, List<Point>> signatureObject = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
private Pen signaturePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
private List<Point> currentCurvePoints = null;
private int currentCurve = -1;

private void pBoxSignature_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    currentCurvePoints = new List<Point>();
    currentCurve += 1;
    signatureObject.Add(currentCurve, currentCurvePoints);
}

private void pBoxSignature_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || currentCurve < 0) return;
    signatureObject[currentCurve].Add(e.Location);
    pBoxSignature.Invalidate();
}

private void btnClearSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    currentCurve = -1;
    signatureObject.Clear();
    pBoxSignature.Invalidate();
}

private void btnSaveSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string signatureFileName = txtSignatureFileName.Text.Trim();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureFileName)) return;
    if (currentCurve < 0 || signatureObject[currentCurve].Count == 0) return;

    var imgSignature = new Bitmap(pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgSignature)) {
        DrawSignature(g);
        string signaturePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, $"{signatureFileName}.png");
        imgSignature.Save(signaturePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        pBoxSavedSignature.Image?.Dispose();
        pBoxSavedSignature.Image = imgSignature;
    }
}

private void pBoxSignature_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentCurve < 0 || signatureObject[currentCurve].Count == 0) return;
    DrawSignature(e.Graphics);
}

private void DrawSignature(Graphics g)
{
    // In case you have composited background
    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

    foreach (var curve in signatureObject) {
        if (curve.Value.Count < 2) continue;

        using (var gPath = new GraphicsPath()) {
            gPath.AddCurve(curve.Value.ToArray(), 0.5f);
            g.DrawPath(signaturePen, gPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jimi, Works like a charm.

Comment: Nice coding, please do not forget adding the following: Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to save as BMP, the background needs to be white because BMP doesnt support Transparency.  With that being said, I have added these 2 lines above the DrawPath call.

```
Dim Brsh As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.White)
g.FillRectangle(Brsh, 0, 0, pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height)
g.DrawPath(signaturePen, gPath)
```

BUT, Now I am no longer able to pickup my pen stroke otherwise all previous strokes get erased/cleared. (Meaning first and last names need to be written without pickup up pen)  Could someone with more knowledge on images perhaps see a reason for this and point me in the direction of a solution?

UPDATE:
Working Code

Here is the code:

```
Using imgSignature As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgSignature)
        g.FillRectangle(Brsh, 0, 0, pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height)
        Call DrawSignature(g)
    End Using
    imgSignature.Save(signaturePath, ImageFormat.Bmp)
    pBoxSavedSignature.Image = New Bitmap(imgSignature)
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jimi.

In case someone need it in C#:

```
public partial class FSignature : Form
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<Point>> signatureObject = new Dictionary<int, List<Point>>();
    private Pen signaturePen = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
    private List<Point> currentCurvePoints;
    private int currentCurve = -1;

    public FSignature()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }





    private void pBoxSignature_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        currentCurvePoints = new List<Point>();
        currentCurve += 1;
        signatureObject.Add(currentCurve, currentCurvePoints);
    }

    private void pBoxSignature_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left || currentCurve < 0)
            return;
        signatureObject[currentCurve].Add(e.Location);
        pBoxSignature.Invalidate();
    }

    private void btnClearSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentCurve = -1;
        signatureObject.Clear();
        pBoxSignature.Invalidate();
    }

    private void btnSaveSignature_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var signatureFileName = txtSignatureFileName.Text.Trim();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(signatureFileName))
            return;
        if (currentCurve < 0 || signatureObject[currentCurve].Count == 0)
            return;
        using (Bitmap imgSignature = new Bitmap(pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imgSignature))
            {
                DrawSignature(g);
                string signaturePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, $"{signatureFileName}.png");
           
                imgSignature.Save(signaturePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                pBoxSavedSignature.Image = new Bitmap(imgSignature);
            }
        }
    }

    private void pBoxSignature_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentCurve < 0 || signatureObject[currentCurve].Count == 0)
            return;
        DrawSignature(e.Graphics);
    }

    private void DrawSignature(Graphics g)
    {
        g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        foreach (var curve in signatureObject)
        {
            if (curve.Value.Count < 2)
                continue;
            using (GraphicsPath gPath = new GraphicsPath())
            {
                gPath.AddCurve(curve.Value.ToArray(), 0.5F);
                g.DrawPath(signaturePen, gPath);
            }
        }
    }


}
```