# After taking a picture using bitmap, it saves to black image

Tags: c#

I want to save digit signatire which I create using pictruebox control to jpeg or png(doesn't matter which file extension). After saving picture it shows black picture. How to avoid black background and save what really is drawn on the picturebox to jpg or png. My code:

```
    public Form4()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bm = new Bitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        pic.Image = bm;
    }

      Bitmap bm;
    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // button save to jpg file
    {
        Bitmap bmp = bm.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height), bm.PixelFormat);
        
        bmp.Save("Signature.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        bmp.Dispose();
    }
```

How to avoid this result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE4IY.jpg)

```
    //Code for drawing a signature:

    float firstX = 0;
    float firstY = 0;

    float LastX = 0;
    float LastY = 0;
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        LastX = e.X;
        LastY = e.Y;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            firstX = e.X;
            firstY = e.Y;
            pictureBox1_Paint(this, null);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 7);
        g = pic.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawLine(pen, firstX, firstY, LastX, LastY);
        LastX = firstX;
        LastY = firstY;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code that captures and displays the digital signature?

Comment: Whatever you're expecting to be in bm, it's clear from the code that it will always be a black image.  You create it with a constructor that takes width and height as parameters, then you never draw anything to it.  Then you clone it to save it.

Comment: g = pic.CreateGraphics(); is a bug, delete that statement to draw into bm.  And use a pen that isn't black...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081239/how-to-draw-a-signature-and-save-it-to-disc-as-a-bitmap

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081239/how-to-draw-a-signature-and-save-it-to-disc-as-a-bitmap) which is a vb.net post with a C# entry that should work for you.

Comment: Start by `g.Clear(Color.White)` to get a defined background, then follow Hans' advice!