# Save a drawing from picturebox to SQL I VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to do a visitor control program and save the visitor info as well their signature to a SQL db. The PictureBox code is working great but I can't save the image, I've searched and I saw that it can also be saved as binary. I don't want to save it locally 'cause it's never the same visitor and my goal is to real put everything on the database. Any ideas on how to solve this?

The code used to draw a signature comes from this SO question:
[How to draw a signature and save it to disc as a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084653/7444103)

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Imports System.IO
Public Class registrovisitas
    Private signatureObject As New Dictionary(Of Integer, List(Of Point))
    Private signaturePen As New Pen(Color.Black, 4)
    Private currentCurvePoints As List(Of Point)
    Private currentCurve As Integer = -1
    Private Sub pBoxSignature_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.MouseDown
        currentCurvePoints = New List(Of Point)
        currentCurve += 1
        signatureObject.Add(currentCurve, currentCurvePoints)
    End Sub
    Private Sub pBoxSignature_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.MouseMove
        If e.Button <> MouseButtons.Left OrElse currentCurve < 0 Then Return
        signatureObject(currentCurve).Add(e.Location)
        pBoxSignature.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Private Sub pBoxSignature_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pBoxSignature.Paint
        If currentCurve < 0 OrElse signatureObject(currentCurve).Count = 0 Then Return
        DrawSignature(e.Graphics)
    End Sub
    Private Sub DrawSignature(g As Graphics)
        g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

        For Each curve In signatureObject
            If curve.Value.Count < 2 Then Continue For
            Using gPath As New GraphicsPath()
                gPath.AddCurve(curve.Value.ToArray(), 0.5F)
                g.DrawPath(signaturePen, gPath)
            End Using
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub registrovisitas_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dtp_FECHA.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        dtp_FECHA.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    End Sub
    Private Sub Nuevo_ID_VISITA()
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim strconsultamax As String = "Select max(ID_RegistroVisitas)+1 as Nuevo_ID_VISITA from [Registro Visitas]"
        rs.Open(strconsultamax, BdSQL, 1, 3)

        lbl_ID.Text = rs("Nuevo_ID_VISITA").Value.ToString

        rs.Close()
        rs = Nothing
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Nuevo_ID_VISITA()

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height)
        pBoxSignature.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, pBoxSignature.Width, pBoxSignature.Height))


        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

        rs.Open("Select * from [Registro Visitas]", BdSQL, 1, 3)
        rs.AddNew()


        If rs.EOF = True Then rs.AddNew()

        rs("ID_RegistroVisitas").Value = lbl_ID.Text
        rs("Fecha_RegistroVisitas").Value = dtp_FECHA.Value
        rs("Visitante_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_VISITANTE.Text
        rs("DNI_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_DNI.Text
        rs("hentrada_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_hE.Text
        rs("NTarjeta_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_mE.Text
        rs("Motivo_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_MOTIVO.Text
        rs("Destinatario_RegistroVisitas").Value = txt_DEST.Text
        rs("FirmaDest_RegistroVisitas").Value = bmp
        rs("Tipo_de_Registro").Value = "1"

        rs.Update()
        MessageBox.Show("S'han guardat els canvis")
        rs.Close()
        rs = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Firstly, I would question why you're using a `Recordset` in a .NET app. You really ought to be using ADO.NET if you're not going to use EF or some other ORM. Unless this is an upgraded VB6 app, there's no good reason to be using a `Recordset`.

Comment: As for the issue, what's the issue? You said that you've seen examples so what exactly are you stuck on? Create a byte array from your image and save that data to the database like you would any other data. Until you have tried to do that, you have no question to ask here.

Comment: Since you took this code directly from here: [How to draw a signature and save it to disc as a Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57084653/7444103), you may have noticed that the code in the save procedure generates a Bitmap, then uses `imgSignature.Save(signaturePath, ImageFormat.Png)` to save it to disk. You can replace the path with a Stream, in your case a `MemoryStream`, save image then take the bytes with `[MemoryStream].ToArray()`, store the bytes in your database

Comment: You can also generate the Bitmap (with a `Using` statement), then use `dim bytes = new ImageConverter().ConvertTo([The Bitmap], GetType(byte()))` to get the byte array from it